# Changing backgroundColor to green if correct, to red if wrong in a quiz. “Cannot find 'layer' in scope”. Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Cannot figure out how to make a short-time change of a color on an answer option cell (not button!), green or red depending on correctness or falsity of the answer.

Searched through the internet, watched some videos, but they are not fully applicable for my case.

E.g. it works inside viewDidLoad(), as in an example on Youtube, it’s possible to add the animation `view.layer.add(animation, forKey: “backgroundColor”)`.

But particularly in my case, I put these methods inside a struct, and it doesn’t define any layers, the error shows up “Cannot find 'layer' in scope”.

So with my very little knowledge of Swift I think that this feature doesn’t work, because I don’t know how to add this animation.

But maybe I am doing it completely wrong at all and it should be done in a completely different way?

```
import UIKit

struct Answer {
  let text: String
  let correct: Bool // true/false
  
  func turnGreen() {
    let go_green = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
    go_green.fromValue = UIColor.white.cgColor
    go_green.toValue = UIColor.green.cgColor
    go_green.duration = 2
    go_green.autoreverses = false
    go_green.repeatCount = 1
    go_green.initialVelocity = 300
    
    layer.add(go_green, forKey: "backgroundColor")
  }
  
  func turnRed() {
    let go_red = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
    go_red.duration = 3
    go_red.fromValue = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    go_red.toValue = UIColor.red.cgColor
    go_red.autoreverses = false
    go_red.repeatCount = 1
  //  go_red.initialVelocity = 3
    
    layer.add(go_red, forKey: "backgroundColor")
  }
}
```

And then I intended to put these `turnGreen()/turnRed()` methods into `private func checkAnswer(for answer: Answer)` in `ViewController`.

```
  private func checkAnswer(for answer: Answer) {
    if answer.correct {
      answer.turnGreen()
      if questionNumber > questions.count {
        // filling the scale fully
        progressView.progress = Float(questions.count)
        score += 1
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        answer.turnGreen()
        
              let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Awesome",
                                            message: "End of Quiz. Do you want to start over?",
                                            preferredStyle: .alert)
              let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart",
                                                style: .default,
                                                handler: { action in self.shuffleQuestions() } )
              alert.addAction(restartAction)
              present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
      }
      answer.turnGreen()
      score += 1
      showQuestion()
    } else {
      // wrong
      
      if questionNumber > questions.count {
        // filling the scale fully
        progressView.progress = Float(questions.count)
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        
              let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Awesome",
                                            message: "End of Quiz. Do you want to start over?",
                                            preferredStyle: .alert)
              let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart",
                                                style: .default,
                                                handler: { action in self.shuffleQuestions() } )
              alert.addAction(restartAction)
              present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
      }
      answer.turnRed()
      showQuestion()
    }
  }
```

Comment: "Cannot figure out how to make a short-time change of a color on an answer option cell (not button!)"... is it a UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell? @Parfen

Comment: The error is expected because layer is a property of UIView. And you are trying to add Animation to ```Answer``` object which doesn't have ```layer``` property.

Comment: @TalhaKuet, I think it’s a UITableViewCell as I had to use those three mandatory UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource methods: numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAt indexPath and didSelectRowAt indexPath.

Comment: Please add the code of  cellForRow, didSelectRow and UITableViewCell. @Parfen

Comment: If you can add a screenshot of your screen in the question that will also help us understand the issue.

Comment: @TalhaKuet, below is the link of my TableViewDelegate and DataSource methods of my GameViewController (in the so called ViewController folder), Answer (from so called Model folder) I already sent in my initial request.    

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I9fabK_fks-rC6-DOdzzO4HknnLE6rif/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Darshan, what exactly do you want me to send? I tried to send here my whole ViewController, but there is a limit on number of characters in comments. It’s better then to send the whole file per email.

Comment: @Parfen - you need to create a custom cell class, which is where you would put your `turnGreen()` and `turnRed()` funcs. Then your controller should tell the **cell** to `turnGreen()` or `turnRed()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `Answer` model should be like this.

```
struct Answer {
    let text: String
    let correct: Bool
}
```

Create a custom UITableViewCell and add `turnGreen()` and `turnRed()` methods to it.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
    
    func turnGreen() {
        let go_green = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
        go_green.fromValue = UIColor.white.cgColor
        go_green.toValue = UIColor.green.cgColor
        go_green.duration = 2
        go_green.autoreverses = false
        go_green.repeatCount = 1
        go_green.initialVelocity = 300
        
        contentView.layer.add(go_green, forKey: "backgroundColor")
    }
    
    func turnRed() {
        let go_red = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
        go_red.duration = 3
        go_red.fromValue = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        go_red.toValue = UIColor.red.cgColor
        go_red.autoreverses = false
        go_red.repeatCount = 1
        //  go_red.initialVelocity = 3
        
        contentView.layer.add(go_red, forKey: "backgroundColor")
    }
}
```

Then register this cell to tableView in `viewDidLoad()` method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
}
```

Change the implementation of `cellForRowAt` and `didSelectRow` methods like below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = answers[indexPath.row].text
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell else { return }
    
    let answer = answers[indexPath.row]
    if answer.correct {
        score += 1
        cell.turnGreen()
    } else {
        cell.turnRed()
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
        self.updateUI()
    }
}
```

I have renamed the method `checkAnswer` to `updateUI`. Here is the code.

```
private func updateUI() {
    progressView.progress = Float(score/questions.count)
    scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
    
    questionNumber += 1
    
    if questionNumber > questions.count {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Awesome",
                                      message: "End of Quiz. Do you want to start over?",
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
        let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart",
                                          style: .default,
                                          handler: { action in self.shuffleQuestions() } )
        alert.addAction(restartAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        showQuestion()
    }
}
```

Comment: @TalhaKuet, thanks a lot for writing such a thorough answer. The matter is that only answering the last question of the quiz, the cell with answer turns green/red. Nothing happens with all the previous answers.  And I cannot get it why. Maybe it is somehow connected with `func checkAnswer()` which is in charge of further actions when the answer is given. And this `func checkAnswer()` is inside `didSelectRowAt` method together with `if answer.correct {cell.turnGreen()} else {cell.turnRed()}` logic. Maybe they are in contradiction somehow, because they are both in charge of the same operation.

Comment: Where do you update the value of ```questionNumber```? @Parfen

Comment: I have updated my answer. Changed implementation of ```checkAnswer``` method and renamed it to ```updateUI```. Also modify the code of ```didSelectRowAt``` method. Please check. @Parfen

Comment: @TalhaKuet, everything works fine! Thank you a lot! I only commented out in `func updateUI()` `questionNumber += 1`, because it is already in `showQuestion()`, so it grew +2 every time. And I changed _score_ in `progressView.progress = Float(score/questions.count)` to _questionNumber-1_, because progressBar grows regardless of correctness/falsity of an answer, but rather from the question number.

Comment: As for the rest I need some time to let it go slowly through my head to understand it.  ) E.g. it’s unclear what `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter etc.` does. But now I tried to test it and commented it out, leaving only `updateUI()`, and everything returned to the previous version: only the last answer started turning green/red again. I need time to comprehend it. @TalhaKuet

Comment: Actually i used ```DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter``` to delay the ```updateUI()``` method for giving 1 second to show the green/red animation. @Parfen

Comment: Therefore, everything works fine only because of this +1 second in `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`? It seems to be true that it actually also worked before (when only the last answer turned colour), it’s just that all answers weren’t visible except for the last one. And they weren’t visible, because we didn’t have that one second to show them, so they switched over to the next one immediately (without showing red/green colour). It’s a strange thing, difficult for me to grasp. @TalhaKuet.